# Displaying ppt and word documents on Django Templates

Tags: django, iframe, powerpoint, document, display

I am working on an e-learning website that has 3 portals; Admin Teacher and Student. The Course materials are uploaded by Admin and viewed by Students. I have displayed the file using iframe. If the file is PDF, it is getting displayed within iframe, but PPT and DOC files are getting downloaded automatically.

Can someone help me with how to display PPT and Doc files within Iframe?

Comment: Because there is no integrated browser tool to open a PPT or Doc file.

Comment: Google Docs and Google PPT provides iframe links, you can try with this and embed in the django template.

Comment: Yes, I tried implementing the same, but the output or the screen says "No Preview Available". Can you help me with this too, please?  @Ajay Kumar